# Execute shell commands through pipe doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Here's my problem. I want to store some frequently used commands in a txt file and use them conveniently.

This is what I did:

Save several commands in a txt file. The contents are

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --port 6006

tensorboard --bind_all --logdir ./ --port 6006

cd ./CodeOfPapers/Seq2Seq_Transformer/
```

Run commands
For example, `cat ./cmds.txt | grep ju | bash`. This works correctly . A jupyter notebook successfully started. (`ju` is the prefix of jupyter)
Or `cat ./cmds.txt | grep te | bash`. This works too.(`te` is the prefix of tensorboard)

However, when I run the third command, which should change my working directory from `./` to `./CodeOfPapers/Seq2Seq_Transformer/`, nothing happened.
Then I tried `cat ./cmds.txt | grep cd | sh`. Still nothing happened.

I'm totally new to Linux shell. Hope you guys could help me figure out what I should do to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Shell aliases and functions would be better

Comment: bash is a very comfortable shell.
* It has a history mechanism (use cursor up and down). 
* It allows to search in the command history: hit Ctrl-R and start typing "jupy", it will show you the last command containing jupy. Press CTRL-R again to find the second-to-last and so on. Press Enter to execute or CTRL-C to abort.

Answer (score 2):

The commands are working, but not as you expect. When you execute

```
cat ./cmds.txt | grep cd | sh
                            ^-- executes result in new subshell
```

... the result of `grep` is piped into a new `sh` process, which happily executes it (with the result of changing the local directory of *that* `sh` process, but not of the outer `bash` process), and then exits. So you see nothing. In the case of other commands, since they do not exit immediately, you can see that their programs are in execution. But not, as you expect, within your current shell, but within their own `sh` sub-shell. Run `ps -A f` from a different terminal and look at the process trees: there will be an extra `sh` node there.

The right(TM) way to do this is, as @Mat writes in comments, is to define aliases or functions. Aliases would look as follows:

```
alias ju='jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --port 6006'
alias te='tensorboard --bind_all --logdir ./ --port 6006'
alias cop='cd ./CodeOfPapers/Seq2Seq_Transformer/'
```

You would typically place them at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, and load them into the current shell by executing `source ~/.bashrc` after editing them. Now, you would be able to execute those ugly commands by just typing `ju`, or `te`, or `cod` (calling the last one `cd` would be... confusing).

Comment: Thanks! Alias is indeed a better choice.